# Databinding Doesn't Create Binding Class

Tags: java, android, class, data-binding

I am following an instruction from [this site](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) but I always get an error whenever I create a binding class.

Here's my code xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="case"
        type="com.cocolam.oblong.domain.Case" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/treeNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{case.tree}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/treeEarned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/treeNumber"
        android:text="@{case.treeEarned}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java file for the binding:

```
 private CocoMainBinding dataBinder = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coco_main, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, thisView);
```

`dataBinder = CocoMainBinding.bind(thisView);`

```
    return thisView;
}
```

But I get errors that CocoMainBinding that says "Cannot resolve symbol". I tried to create this: import com.cocolam.oblong.databinding.CocoMainBinding; but the error was still there.

What are suggestions to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your build gradle configuration, I guess you're already using gradle version >= 1.5.0 and enabled databinding? Also try build clean, delete .gradle, .idea folders from your project folder and rebuild, File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: @random , thanks :) after "Invalidate Caches/Restart" I was able to make a binding class. Thanks :) .

Comment: great! happy coding :)